# Big nested JSON data and updating DOM when changed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm dealing with pretty big amounts of json and the data is something like this:

```
{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "age": 32,
    "employed": true,
    "address": {
        "street": "701 First Ave.",
        "city": "Sunnyvale, CA 95125",
        "country": "United States"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Richard",
            "age": 7,
            "field": {
                "field": "value"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Whenever I change anything I get a new response which is somewhat similar to the previous data, but where new properties might have been added, stuff might have been removed and so on.

My testcode is something like this (don't mind the infinite amount of bad practices here):

```
<div data-viewmodel="whatevz">
    <span data-bind="text: stuff['nested-thingy']"></span>
</div>
<script>
    function vm() {
        var self = this;
        this.stuff = ko.observable();

        require(["shop/app"], function (shop) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                self.stuff(shop.stuff);
            }, 1200);
        });
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new vm(), $("[data-viewmodel]")[0]);
</script>
```

I want stuff['nested-thingy'] to be updated whenever stuff is updated. How do I do this without all kinds of mapping and making everything observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have to update your biding:

```
<div data-viewmodel="whatevz">
    <span data-bind="text: stuff()['nested-thingy']"></span>
</div>
```

You have to access the value of the observable with the (). That returns your object and then you can access it. The content of the binding is still dependent on the observable stuff therefore it should update whenever stuff is updated.

At least my fiddle is working that way: http://jsfiddle.net/delixfe/guM4X/

```
<div data-bind="if: stuff()">
    <span data-bind="text: stuff()['nested-thingy']"></span>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: add1">1</button>
<button data-bind="click: add2">2</button>
```

Note the `data-bind="if: stuff()`. That is necessary if your stuff's content is empty at binding time or later...

```
function Vm() {
    var self = this;
    self.stuff = ko.observable();

    self.add1 = function () {
        self.stuff({'nested-thingy': "1"});
    };

    self.add2 = function () {
        self.stuff({'nested-thingy': "2"});
    };        


}

ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to deal with the mapping for you? You can use the copy option for the properties that you don't want to be made observables:

```
var mapping = {
    'copy': ["propertyToCopy"]
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

Comment: It just seems like overkill to me. I don't want to have hundreds of databound nested objects on 0.6 mb JSON that will be updated 10 times or more on every page. I'm also afraid that databinding so much data over and over again will be slow. Can someone elaborate here?

Comment: Well, you could use the ignore property to only copy over the data you care about for that section of the page. I take it that your example is an over-simplification, and you want to bind to more than just one property from your nested objects?

Comment: Yes, everything from the JSON response may or may not be used depending on what page you're on. Is there some way I can tell Knockout that an object is changed and everything using descendant properties or arrays should be updated?

Comment: You could store your json data in a variable once you've downloaded it, and then when you change sections of the page, you map the stored json using the mapping plugin with different properties copied and ignored. Would that do what you want?

Comment: Currently I use the Dust template engine to render everything and it's so easy to work with since I simply re-render the template with the new object as context every time it's updated. But I could integrate things better with our CMS if I use Knockout. I think having to map sections that have changed would require a lot more code, and in that case I should probably stick with what I've got or another solution...